# Algorithm to find a simple path with maximum weight less than a constant in DAG

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, np-hard

Given a weighted directed acyclic graph $G=(V,E,W)$, where the weights are non-negative and are on the vertices. I am searching for a simple path of maximum total weight, but this total weight should not exceed a given constant $K$.

Perhaps my question is elementary but I cannot find any solution. Indeed, it is well known that finding a simple path with maximum weight in $G$ is polynomial, but by adding the fact that this total weight should not exceed a given constant $K$, will the problem remain polynomial? because we need to keep at each node the set of path lengths that can be reached by the next vertices.

Comment: Have you tried to construct a reduction?  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: I though first that it is as hard as the problem of searching a simple path of weight $K$ in DAG, since this later is NP-hard (reduction from the subset sim problem), so the problem of finding a simple path of maximum weight at most $K$ is also NP-hard, but I was not sure especially when I read this post https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5430/path-of-exact-cost-in-edge-labelled-dag  where they say that when the weights are all less than a given value than the problem can be solved in polynomial time !

Comment: Even in the answer given to the question you link to, the algorithm is not necessarily polynomial in the size of the instance if  $C$ is a part of the instance description, as $C$ can be coded in $\log_2(C)$ bits and $C$ can thus be exponential in the size of the instance (it is only a pseudo-polynomial-time algorithm). On the other hand, if $K$ is truly a constant independent of the instance, then the algorithm mentioned in that post is also polynomial in your case.

Comment: yes $K$ is truly a constant, but if at each node we calculate the set of path lengths how the complexity of the algorithm could be $O(nmK)$? On the other hand, do you think that the problem cited above is as hard as searching for a simple path of length $K$? if so this later is NP-hard by a reduction from the subset sum problem!

Comment: It is not NP-hard to search for a path of length $K$, if $K$ is a constant.

Comment: Are negative weights allowed?

Comment: no, negative weights are not allowed

Comment: @xskxzr but I am searching for a simple path of maximum total weight, and this total weight should not exceed a constant $K$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no negative weight, you only need to keep at each node the set of path lengths no more than $K$. Because $K$ is a constant, you only keep a constant number of path lengths at each node. Hence, the algorithm remains polynomial-time.